# How can I remove regular line jumps?

Tags: d3.js

How can I remove regular line jumps, and connect date1 to the first chart, the second to the second chart, etc?
I just started to study d3js and do not understand how to bind that data-dataset=[data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6];
var data1=[38 ,33, 42, 121 ,122...]
https://codepen.io/Anfusioon/pen/VwadEdB

```js
var n = 40,
  random = d3.randomNormal(0, .2),
  data = d3.range(n).map(random);
var data1 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data2 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data3 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data4 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data5 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data6 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
dataset = [data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6];


var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, n - 1]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-1, 1]).range([height, 0]);


var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x(i);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return y(d);
  });


var svg = d3.select("#div")
  .selectAll("uniqueChart")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

var path = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .on("start", tick);


function tick() {


  data.push(random());

  d3.select(this)
    .attr("d", valueline)
    .attr("transform", null);


  d3.active(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
    .transition()
    .on("start", tick);


  data.shift();
}
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgb(200, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by line jumps? The moments when the line jumps backwards?

Comment: Yes, I need a smooth movement like here https://codepen.io/Anfusioon/pen/KKzebLL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you modified *the same* data object for every one of the 6 traces. A potential workaround is to only allow the first plot to change the data, as I did below.

Another one would be to perform a deep copy of the data and have every trace use its own copy.

More of a workaround would be to slow the transition down to take 3000ms and use `x(-6)` instead of `x(-1)`. That makes the entire transition seemless, even if it doesn't solve the underlying problem.

```js
var n = 40,
  random = d3.randomNormal(0, .2),
  data = d3.range(n).map(random);
var data1 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data2 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data3 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data4 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data5 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
var data6 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, ];
dataset = [data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6];


var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, n - 1]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-1, 1]).range([height, 0]);


var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x(i);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return y(d);
  });


var svg = d3.select("#div")
  .selectAll("uniqueChart")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

var path = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
  .datum((d, i) => ({ data: data, first: i === 0 }))
  .attr("class", "line")
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .on("start", tick);


function tick(d) {
  if(d.first) {
    data.push(random());
  }

  d3.select(this)
    .attr("d", valueline(d.data))
    .attr("transform", null);

  d3.active(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
    .transition()
    .on("start", tick);

  if(d.first) {
    data.shift();
  }
}
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgb(200, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

---

**Edit** You say you're using different objects. Javascript doesn't care whether two objects have the same values, it only cares whether two variables point to the same object instance.

In this case, I updated your code snippet to use the `dataset` variable, updated the domain to be larger than [-1, 1], and added the option to place either 40, or all data points on the chart.

I removed the things I did in the first part of the answer, and made sure to point at `d` instead of the global variable `data`. Now, the result looks smooth.

```js
var random = d3.randomNormal(0, .2);
var data1 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108];
var data2 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108];
var data3 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108];
var data4 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108];
var data5 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108];
var data6 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108, 38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153, 132, 72, 0, -36, -48, -37, -38, -38, -32, -22, -47, -32, -25, -37, -37, -28, -38, -35, -34, -23, 44, 49, 15, -22, -45, -25, 9, 348, 94, -108];
var dataset = [data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6];
var n = 40; // but could also be d3.max(dataset, (d) => Math.max(d));
var domain = [
  d3.min(dataset, (d) => d3.min(d)),
  d3.max(dataset, (d) => d3.max(d))
];

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, n - 1]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain(domain).range([height, 0]);

var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x(i);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return y(d);
  });


var svg = d3.select("#div")
  .selectAll("uniqueChart")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

var path = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
  .datum((d) => d)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .on("start", tick);


function tick(d) {
  d.push(random());

  d3.select(this)
    .attr("d", valueline)
    .attr("transform", null);

  d3.active(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
    .transition()
    .on("start", tick);

  d.shift();
}
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgb(200, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well. I need to plot a graph for each array, all arrays are different, not copies of each other. eg:var data1 = [38, 33, 42, 121, 122, 147, 153...];
var data2 = [2,-101, -131, -117, -119, -129, -105, -68, -54...].  I will immediately remove the random number generator as soon as I can start the graph using data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6.

Comment: Being the same is not about the values, but about the array itself. You use `data` everywhere, instead of `data1, data2` etc

Comment: Сan you explain in more detail, preferably with a code snippet? How to pass different data for each graph?(`data1` for the first, `data2` for the secound, etc) https://codepen.io/Anfusioon/pen/BaKPWBW here, instead of random numbers, data from `date1` now goes, and other graphs copy them

Comment: I updated the answer already, there is a second code snippet. I treat `dataset` as an array and create one SVG for every entry